# How to abort HTTP request in Firefox Addon SDK

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, request, firefox-addon-sdk

The `Request` object in Firefox Addon SDK doesn't seem to offer an `abort` function:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.1/packages/addon-kit/docs/request.html

Did I miss a way to abort HTTP requests or do I have to modify 
`packages\addon-kit\lib\request.js`

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you're missing anything. Post to the [mozilla-labs-jetpack group](http://groups.google.com/group/mozilla-labs-jetpack), [open a bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Add-on%20SDK), or even directly [a pull request](https://github.com/mozilla/addon-sdk) adding the feature if you're feeling lucky.